# UPS Shipping REST API

Tags: api, rest, restful-url, ups

I am wanting to make a dummy REST call using UPS's API to generate a test fake shipment request.

I am following the REST UPS documentation for the shipping package:

```
https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US
```

Page 116 shows an example of a client application creating a shipment and getting a successful response with a shipping label. I would like to re-create this so I have attempted to POST some fake data to the TEST URL address:

```
https://wwwcie.ups.com/ship/v1/shipments
```

I make the request (with header and body information), but I keep receiving error code 120100 (missing or invalid shipper number).

A lot of forums posts are saying it has something to do with my address not being setup on my UPS account, but I already have an address setup on my account, and I just want to make a fake request to the TEST URL endpoint.

Here is the body of request:

```
{
"ShipmentRequest":{
"Shipment":{ "Description":"1206 PTR", "Shipper":{
"Name":"ShipperName", "AttentionName":"AttentionName", "TaxIdentificationNumber":"TaxID", "Phone":{
"Number":"1234567890" },
"ShipperNumber":"ShipperNumber", "Address":{
"AddressLine":"AddressLine", "City":"City", "StateProvinceCode":"STD", "PostalCode":"PostalCode", "CountryCode":"EN"
} },
"ShipTo":{
"Name":"ShipToName", "AttentionName":"AttentionName", "Phone":{
"Number":"1234567890" },
"FaxNumber":"1234567999", "TaxIdentificationNumber":"456999", "Address":{
"AddressLine":"AddressLine", "City":"City", "StateProvinceCode":"STD", "PostalCode":"PostalCode", "CountryCode":"EN"
} },
"ShipFrom":{ "Name":"ShipperName", "AttentionName":"AttentionName", "Phone":{
"Number":"1234567890" },
"FaxNumber":"1234567999", "TaxIdentificationNumber":"456999", "Address":{
"AddressLine":"AddressLine", "City":"City",
"StateProvinceCode":"STD", "PostalCode":"PsotalCode", "CountryCode":"EN"
} },
"PaymentInformation":{ "ShipmentCharge":{
"Type":"01", "BillShipper":{
"AccountNumber":"AccountNumber" }
} },
"Service":{
"Code":"01", "Description":"Expedited"
},
"Package":[{ "Description":"International Goods", "Packaging":{
"Code":"02" },
"PackageWeight":{ "UnitOfMeasurement":{
"Code":"LBS" },
"Weight":"10" },
"PackageServiceOptions":"" },
{
"Description":"International Goods", "Packaging":{
"Code":"02" },
"PackageWeight":{ "UnitOfMeasurement":{
"Code":"LBS" },
"Weight":"20" },
"PackageServiceOptions":"" }]
, "ItemizedChargesRequestedIndicator":"", "RatingMethodRequestedIndicator":"", "TaxInformationIndicator":"", "ShipmentRatingOptions":{
"NegotiatedRatesIndicator":"" }
}, "LabelSpecification":{
"LabelImageFormat":{ "Code":"GIF"
} }
} }
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by finding the Shipper Number (Account Number) linked to the UPS developer account.